# Detect discrepancy between compiled jar and code in repo

Tags: java, maven, decompiling

One of contractors at my current project has a weird habit to deploy fixes to the production as jars and not to push fixed code to the project's git repo. There are tens of maven projects which packs to a jars

Is there any practical way to detect and plot all discrepancies between compiled jars from production and code from a repo? Currently I can decompile a jar with IDEA and compare result with code. Decompiled code is not identical to original by design so it takes ages and possibly leads to errors.

Comment: It is your contractor that needs to be fixed; for you to have to do this with any hopes of a reliable result is unrealistic.

Comment: Contractor fixes this issues only if forced to do that... That a real problem. I need at least detect all diverged files

Comment: Yeah, but the contractor should also update your codebase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To detect changed classes, I would compile the code in the codebase and make a class by class binary comparison between the class files you just created and the ones in production. This can be easily automated.

But the real solution is of course: Your company should have a rule that only builds from the build server (Jenkins, Bamboo, whatever) that draw from the official git repo can go to production. No exceptions.

Answer (score 1):

The technical solution to your problem is called [Reproducible_builds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reproducible_builds).

But i donot think that you need a technical solution for the "blaming-game" but an organisational solution like overwrite the production build with your own jar compilation and refuse to pay the contractor if the problem re-appears